# cannot convert from 'const char [3]' to 'char *' x100000 (Qt Creator C++ Windows 32)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, 32-bit

Everything was working fine just five minutes ago when I tapped f5 and got 102 errors:

```
error: C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [17]' to 'char *'
Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)
```

That specific one is at line 30:

```
char* hexchars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

I haven't touched the file the errors are in for at least a week. I'd normally say I accidentally changed something in the compile args or something, but I haven't opened settings since much before it started erroring.

Any ideas? I must have absentmindedly changed some setting but I really can't remember thinking "uh oh what did I just do?"

Comment: That's been bad code forever, you finally turned on a compile option that points it out.  Instead of disabling the warning, fix the code (change from `char*` to `const char*`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use code like this

```
char *astring2 = "some letters";
```

C++ (and C) puts that into read only memory.  You can not modify the contents of a char pointer initialized with a literal even if it is not const.

Also you can not change the address of the pointer because it will cause a memory leak due to the rule above.

This, however, does not follow that rule UNLESS you make it const:

```
char astring[] = "some letters that can be changed";
char *ptrToString = astring; //work
astring2 = astring //not work
```

Comment: With the latter, you can get the size of the text by using `sizeof(astring) - 1U`.  The `-1` removes the `'\0'` from the count.

Comment: "`astring2 = astring` //not work"  Are you talking about the `char* astring` above?  If you are, then yes that does work, you can make a pointer to an array just fine.  (Assuming you provide the missing semicolon)

Comment: the address of a char * initialized with a string literal can not be changed (char * not to be confused with char[]  although technically they are the same)

Comment: Thanks (and the other answer, too). I'm a bit confused why I saw neither warning nor error before today, but I guess in a few years my code will probably completely invalid anyway...

Answer (score 5):

String literals are of type `char const[N]` since C++ was first standardized. At this point C didn't support `const` and a lot of code assigned string literals to `char*`. As a result a special rule was present in C++ which allowed initialization of `char*` from string literals. This rule was immediately deprecated.

C99 introduced a `const` keyword, too. When C++11 was standardized the deprecated rules was pulled and it is no illegal to initialize a `char*` from a string literal as it should have been right from the stand. The expectation was that C++ compilers warned about the deprecated assignment since years (and all vendors stated they did), i.e., users had years of lead-time to fix their code.

The obvious fix is to initialize a `char const*` instead of a `char*` from a string literal.

If you really need a pointer to a mutable array of `char`s you can create it and get it initialized using

```
char array[] = "string literal";
```

Comment: `const` appeared in c89. Typo?