# Problems with types in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: c++

As I know in C++ you can change the value of (`char *`) variable , but I have an error.

[image: This is a screenshot.]

The error is:

```
error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char [71]' to 'char *'
```

before I declared a `char*` variable:

```
char *sql;
```

and then I want to use it, but:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO person (id,name,last,age) "  \
    "VALUES (1, 'Paul', 'Yezh', 14); ";
```

On the equal sign I have this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot convert from 'const char \[3\]' to 'char \*' x100000 (Qt Creator C++ Windows 32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244225/cannot-convert-from-const-char-3-to-char-x100000-qt-creator-c-windows)

Comment: Mostly duplicate: [How to get rid of `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` warnings in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-warnin) The warning has since been promoted to an error because, face it, assigning `const` data of any stripe to a non-const` pointer is a bad idea. By the way, ignore the accepted answer. It's no longer valid.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2745495). Instead, add and **[format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** your code into the post itself as **text**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since character strings are constant arrays, you need to change the type of `sql` to `const char *sql`.

Comment: Or copy the string if it needs to be modified.

Comment: This answer is correct. Consider also that all compiler errors are well documented online. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx) for a clear and easy explanation of the C2440 error. Always check documentation.